# What is the optimal way to retrieve a continuously varying value from elastic search

Tags: elasticsearch

I am currently building an Elastic Index and I have the need to get a total count that is continuously changing.

I have a User mapping, a Group mapping and an Activity mapping. The Group can have a few different Activity IDs and a User can join a Group, I then place the Group ID in the user.

I have a need to get a Count of all users within a Group that has Activity X. This count will happen every time a user logs in, I am expecting this to happen multiple times per second. This means that I need a query to filter for all Groups with Activity X, retrieve the ID and then query all Users with Group ID 'Z' and return a count.

I am quite new to Elastic so I am trying to not think like a SQLdb but my brain tells me to just insert a counter in the Activity mapping that will get incremented every time a User joins a Group and decremented every time a user leaves. The issue is that in my specific project, this will happen often (hundreds/hour). I will also need to increment multiple Activities if a user joins a Group that has multiple Activities.

I may be getting ahead of myself but I am trying to think efficiently so as to not cause mapping problems later on.

Should I be using a counter in Activities and do a simple Get Counter from Activity X or perform multiple queries to get a total count?

Thanks ahead of time for any insight!

Comment: although I did not understand everything 100%, i think you can easily achieve this with [count api](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-count.html)

Comment: I think the count api would work once I have a list of all the Group IDs. I only have the Activity ID to do the search so I will need to do a query to get all Groups that contain the Activity, then use the count api to get a count of all users that contain the Group ID. Would that be better than incrementing a counter?

Comment: As Elasticsearch isn't the best DB when it comes to "joins" (although it does have nested and child/parent structures) a graph database like neo4j or just a relational db might be better suited for this task. How many distinct users, groups and activities do you expect to have? Or if groups' activities don't change that often you could directly store activites to user documents. Then ES queries will be trivial to write and documents are quite easy to keep up to date.